# CORS policy blocks DELETE request despite allowing all methods in web.config

Tags: c#, angular, iis, cors

I have C# WebAPI and an Angular front end application. All the http requests work well in the dev environment, but deploying both server and UI on IIS was having issues with the CORS policy restrictions.

I was able to read through some material and modify my code to allow the communication. So I am allowing all headers and methods using the `IIS CORS module`, in my `web.config` file deployed on IIS here is the relevant code that i put :

```
    <system.webServer>
    <cors enabled="true">
      <add origin="*">
        <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true" />
        <allowMethods>
            <add method="GET" />
            <add method="HEAD" />
            <add method="POST" />
            <add method="PUT" /> 
            <add method="DELETE" />    
        </allowMethods>
        <exposeHeaders>
            <add header="header1" />
            <add header="header2" />
        </exposeHeaders>
      </add>
    </cors>

</system.webServer>
```

So now my GET and POST requests work as expected but my DELETE requests keep getting the same error :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed
```

Could it be because of a missing configuration or is it anything to do with the actual delete request, which is sending an email address at the end of the delete request (e.g. in the above example, I'm sending an email : `NewReq@NewReq.com`)?

Can someone please help me figure this out?

Comment: Why are you configuring CORS in two different places (IIS and C#)? One should be enough. Start there.

Comment: Please remove your hack of `<customHeaders>` and switch to IIS CORS module, https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/getting-started-with-the-iis-cors-module

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but configuring as per this document now gives me error ```Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)``` updating the question to show the current web.config

Comment: Using logging is a great way to diagnose server-side problems. When getting a status 405 response, it can be helpful to check both server and application logs.

Comment: removing ```WebDAV``` from the roles and features stopped the error. But I am not sure that is a good solution.